# Simplify (4/5 - 3i/5)^75

Tags: complex-numbers

Simplify $\left(\dfrac{4}{5} - \dfrac{3}{5}i\right)^{\!75}$

I've searched around on the internet and haven't found a very straightforward answer for this particular problem. I believe this problem has something to do with Euler's Formula, but I'm not sure how to use it in this case.

EDIT: We are not allowed to use calculators for this problem.

Comment: do you really want to compute this?

Comment: Its a problem on an example final which our professor gave us. She never really went over how to do this type of problem.

Comment: Hint : Calculate the absolute value and the argument of $4/5-3/5i$. By the way, is it $\frac{3}{5}\cdot i$ or $\frac{3}{5\cdot i}$ ? What is clear, that the absolute value of the desired number is $1$, but how can we calculate the argument WITHOUT using a calculator ?

Comment: Sorry @Peter, my mathjax wasn't working. Its (3/5)*i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$\left(\frac45\right)^2+\left(\frac35\right)^2=1$$
So there exists an angle $\alpha$ such that
$$\frac45-\frac35i=e^{i\alpha}$$
Then
$$\left(\frac45-\frac35i\right)^{75}=e^{i75\alpha}=\cos(75\alpha)+i\sin(75\alpha)$$

I don't think that there is a simple way to express it with exact fractions. The denominator would be $5^{75}$ which has $53$ digits, and there is no reason, as far as I know, to think that the fractions can be written in much smaller terms.

The real part, for example, is
$$\frac1{5^{75}}\sum_{n=0}^{37}\binom{75}{2n}(-1)^n 4^{75-2n}3^{2n}=\left(\frac45\right)^{75}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{37}\binom{75}{2n}\left(-\frac9{16}\right)^n$$

Comment: `don't think that there is a simple way to express it with exact fractions` Especially not without a calculator. For example Wolfram Alpha [gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(75+atan(-3%2F4))):

$$
\cos\left(75 \,\arctan(-\frac{3}{4})\right) = -\frac{11085051570026481464865151104053349166066117238958284}{26469779601696885595885078146238811314105987548828125}
$$

Comment: Right; I'm not sure what the department was expecting with this problem. I think going as far as the cos(75Θ) + i*sin(75Θ) would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what happens when you take a power of a complex number on the unit circle, which can be written as $e^{i\phi}$